# How can I define Lambda Expression for an interface with more than one method?

Tags: java, lambda, interface

I can not define a lambda expression for an interface with multiple methods shown in the code below.

```java
interface Interface{
    public void st1();
    public String ra(String p);
}
```

I can define a lambda expression for a single-method interface.

```java
interface Interface{
    public String ra(String p);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface r = (x)->{
        return x;
    };
    String getValue = r.ra("string");
    System.out.println(getValue);
}
```

But how can I define a lambda Expression for multiple methods?

Comment: How about an anonymous class instead?

Comment: Lambda expressions and method references can only be used with _functional interfaces_, which are interfaces that have only a single abstract method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6). Anonymously defining a class with a lambda expression is a syntactic sugar that's only available for interfaces with a single method. If you have more than one method, you'll have to resort to a good old fashioned anonymous class:

```java
Interface r = new Interface() {
    public void st1() {
        // do something;
    }

    public String ra(String p) {
        return p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like the look of it better you could write:

```
interface Interface{
    public void st1();
    public String ra(String p);
    public static Interface build(Runnable st1, Function<String,String> ra) {
        return new Interface() {

            @Override
            public void st1() {
                st1.run();
            }

            @Override
            public String ra(String p) {
                return ra.apply(p);
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface thing = Interface.build(
                () -> System.out.println("foo"),
                String::toUpperCase
        );
    }
}
```

Perhaps there are circumstances where that's clearer.

If you have two methods with the same signature I would *not* recommend this -- unless you use the builder pattern, but then a simple anonymous class is likely to be clearer.